# How to Cakephp 2x User Login thorught curl outside form cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.2

How to Cakephp 2x User Login thorught curl outside form cakephp.

After successfully Login i want to get login user details or login not success get message "login failed"

**this is my cakephp directory**

```
cakephp->app
cakephp->demo
```

**Below my code:**

**Demo/index.php**

```
$urltopost = "http://localhost/eventapp/users/androide_login";


$fields = array(
    'User'=>array(
    'username' => 'demo',
    'password' => '123456789'

    )
);
 $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);


print_r($returndata); //display the reuslt*/
```

**This is my UsersController/login action**

```
public function androide_login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login($this->data)) {
            $user = $_SESSION['Auth']['User'];
            pr($this->Session->read('Auth.User'));
            die;

        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.');
        }
    } 

}
```

About the code not working properly.

Comment: What happens right now? Why don't you storing cookies?

Comment: but i have send request through from in cakephp. UsersController/login given correct output. but i have send request through curl with same format "according to cakephp" but get wrong result why?

Comment: I've asked two questions.

Comment: any answer ? I am facing the same issue . How can i set the cookies in cake php app from yii application ?